# A question on probability and expectation concepts

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, statistics, quantum-statistics

Let A be an observable event. If the expectation of A is zero, does it imply that the probability of A is zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the answer is no, it does not. Oftentimes $A$ can be a positive or a negative quantity, so it can average to zero even when it never actually takes the value of zero.

For example, if you are measuring the position of an object relative to you, you might find it to be $10$ metres in front of you half of the time and $10$ metres behind you the other half of the time. On average, the object is exactly at the same position as you (so the expectation value is zero), but there is zero probability of finding the object exactly where you are.

Comment: Thanks @Quantum Mechanic. I have another doubt.  Let A and B be two events. Suppose that the mean values of A and B are null and yet, that the act of measuring one event does not necessarily affect the other. Based on the above, is it possible to take A and B as statistical independence events?

Comment: This is a completely different question. If the act of one measurement does not affect the other then they should be statistically independent